# How to bash as normal user in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I use `docker exec -it myapp bash` to "SSH" to the container and I'm always logged as `root` right away. When I type `exit`, I exit out of the container instead of logging out as `root`. Is it possible to just login as non-root user in a Docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the *[-u](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user)* option :

```
docker exec -it -u $another_user myapp bash
```

**EDIT** : <s>the "another_user" must exist in the container.</s>

**EDIT2** (With the help of David Maze) : the "another_user" must exist in the container, but you can use whatever id you want : 1234, 7711, etc.(does not need to exist!)

Comment: Can the user be an arbitrary user that does't exist yet in the image?

Comment: Nope, you cannot switch to an undefined user.

Comment: The user has to exist in your container, indeed! If your container only has root user, you can create a new user in it... but that's not the way to do it the correct way.

Comment: @Marvin Ok I created a new user in the `Dockerfile` but my problem now is I don't know the `root` password of the container so I can't eventually use `su -` from that new user. Any ideas?

Comment: You can totally switch to an undefined user; try `docker exec -u 12345` or your choice of arbitrary numeric uid.

Comment: @David Maze my bad : never realized tjat nefpre. I'll edit my answer once more.
> IMB not sure here, and can't try atm. But you can try this : create a new image FROM this image, and add "USER root". I'll try it as soon as I have the opportunity

Comment: Actually, I realized it's not that big a deal if I can't `su -` I can simply bash out and bash in as root anyway.